# Folding paper into corners

Tags: geometry, paper-folding

Here is a piece of paper:

[image: A rectangular piece of paper]

Fold it once, and you can get a shape with 9 corners:

[image: Paper folded once, resulting in 9 corners]

Starting with a rectangular sheet of paper and folding *twice* (along any line), what is the largest possible number of corners that may result?

**Rule for counting corners**: both concave and convex corners count (as you can see in the example), but they must not be "covered" by the rest of the paper. In other words, you are counting the corners of the silhouette.

*Credit: Alex C Weiner*

Comment: Nice puzzle - you may have to ask to fold it thrice. So far 0, 1, 2 folds give 4,  9, 16 corners - looks interesting!

Comment: Is it inspired from [Paperama(an origami based game)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fdgentertainment.paperama&hl=en)?

Comment: @Tom Yes please, what is the answer for 3 folds? I have no idea.

Comment: @Tom, I see pattern of (x+2)^2

Comment: @Owen - it looks tough - you could ask as a new question!

Comment: May need to say if can just fold the rectangle or along any line.

Comment: If you make it even thinner, you can fold the 16-solution like this https://nup.pw/QhvFL5.png, giving 28 corners. So, (x+2)^2 is not optimal.

Comment: Carl you have missed two concave corners in your diagram, so the answer for three folds must be at least 30.

Comment: @Penguino oh, right :-) thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Tom, prove it.

Comment: @carl I see 4 folds.

Comment: @ev3commander I think the top 2 folds are supposed to be collinear (making it one fold).

Comment: @CarlLöndahl: The 5-pointed star made from a thin strip folded 4 times has: 5 inner triangles, a central pentagon, 5 exterior angles, 2x4 "fold" corners, plus the 9 angles from crossing the two strip ends, for a total of 15 + 5 + 5 +8 +9 = 42, so the "rule" does not hold.

Comment: Also, the shape that looks like a star trek badge, but with the two ends extending up and out (3 folds) has 29 angles.

Comment: @Owen, right. It was supposed to look collinear :-) Drawing is hard.

Comment: @Benjamin  Shouldn't it be 25 for three folds? Where does 29 come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a long and thin rectangular strip, you can get up to

> $17$ corners.

Here's how:

> [image: Fold by Fold visualization]

Comment: The last three corners come from the triangular hole inside the shape.

Comment: Looks like a new winner!

Answer (score 53):

I managed to make

> $16$ corners with a thin strip, or $15$ with any rectangle including a square.

Like so:

> **For a strip:**
>
>  [image: photo of folded paper]
>
>  [image: instructions to fold paper]
>
>  **For a square:**
>
>   [image]
>  - fold along the red lines
>  (the black lines on the back are the same as the front except rotated to have the 16th lines in the bottom quarter rather than the top one.)
>  [image: square instructions]
>
>  For a rectangle with less width than height do the same but move the first red line's ends nearer the centre and the second red line's ends nearer the quarter marks (at some point you can make $16$ corners instead though).

Comment: Is this always possible for an arbitrary n x m rectangle? I feel like it isn't but I wouldn't know how to go about proving that.

Comment: @RowlandB It needs to be pretty thin to allow both the hole and the two ends to cross (try it with an A4 sheet!); I have not calculated the limits.

Comment: @RowlandB - I added a case for one less corner that works for a square.

Comment: The strip thing didn't convince me (as not following the spirit of this challenge), but the second part deserves a +1.

Comment: As far as the strip goes, I believe this is possible with any strip whose long to short side ration is greater than exactly 10/sqrt(3).  Will post diagram later.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ph8DPCb.png <-- diagram.  Showing the limits as the hole shrinks to a point and the sticking out corners reduce to touching an edge.  I am assuming that this is minimal when using symmetric equilateral triangles, but you could do some calculus on varying the angles to find out.
+1 to JA for considering identifying a case outside the general case.

Answer (score 17):

I have managed to come up with

> 14 corners with two folds.

Following are the images of the paper with each fold.

> Unfolded [image]

> One fold [image]

> Two folds [image]

> Corners highlighted [image]

Answer (score 7):

> 14

by

> take a strip of paper (still technically a rectangle) and fold it so the ends cross leaving a triangular hole.